# UIButton is not working in the header of my UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibutton

I can't figure out why this `UIButton` is not working in the header of my `UITableView`. It's appearing there but the touch is not working.

The NSLog statement isn't triggering either. It's almost like it's beneath another view or something so that you can see it but the press action doesn't work.

thanks for any help with this

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

UIView *sectionHeader = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectNull];
sectionHeader.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

[sectionHeader addSubview:self.topMapView];

// add map launch button
mapLaunchButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[mapLaunchButton addTarget:self
                    action:@selector(mapButtonTouch:)
          forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[mapLaunchButton setTitle:@"ggggggg" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
mapLaunchButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 90);
mapLaunchButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

[sectionHeader addSubview:mapLaunchButton];


  //  [sectionHeader bringSubviewToFront:mapLaunchButton];

    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = sectionHeader;

    return sectionHeader;

}
- (void)mapButtonTouch:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"map button was touched");
}
```

Comment: In my case the view that contained the uibutton had the userInteraction tick disabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see more than one mistake -

1. If your table has only one section (to verify this check for `numberOfSectionsInTableView` delegate) then remove this line -

   self.tableView.tableHeaderView = sectionHeader;
2. Set `sectionHeader.frame` to something appropriate (not `CGRectNull`). The benefit of setting section header (versus table header view) is that when user will scroll the table rows then the section header will stick on top (float) and will not go away. (Plain style table)
3. Still the problem is not resolved, then please verify his method -

   -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
   {
      return 50;  // depending upon the height of the sectionHeader
   }
4. As pointed out by other poster, to capture touch event on UIButton `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` is preferred event.

**EDIT** - (as table header view implementation)

If you want to scroll it up then make it as table header (not section header). So remove all this from viewForHeaderInSection and put it inside `viewDidLoad` of your view controller class. Keep this line (don't remove it in this case) -

```
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = sectionHeader;
```

However, above points 2 and 4 still holds true.

Comment: thanks, quick thing if I remove      self.tableView.tableHeaderView = sectionHeader; then the header no longer scrolls up with the table view

Comment: also, I'm sure you'll know what this means: if I change 
    [sectionHeader addSubview:self.mapLaunchButton]; to [self.view addSubview:self.mapLaunchButton]; the UIButton works but of course it doesn't scroll then because it's part of the self.view instead of the header. thanks again for your help

Answer (score 2):

If you change `UIControlEventTouchDown` to `UIControlEventTouchUpInside`?

Comment: thanks but that's not it. This was working in another view before I added it the the table header.

Answer (score 1):

One thing is the `section header`, and another is the `table header`. You are assigning the same view as both. I'm not sure this is the cause of your problem, but it's something to get you started.

Instead of implementing that method, on your viewDidLoad, create that view and assign it as the `self.tableView.tableHeaderView`

Additionally, the most common user experience is associated with the `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` (the action will not execute until the finger is lifted and still inside the button). However this likely has nothing to do with your issue. It's just a matter of when the action is called.

If this doesn't fix your issue let me know and I'll try to check if there's something else I've missed

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If you add a view

```
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = ({
        UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 184.0f)];
```

you can add new components: `UIImageView, UIlabel...` 
Its works for me!
I tested.

The final code:

```
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = ({
        UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 184.0f)];
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 40, 100, 100)];
 imageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
        imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"avatar.jpg"];
        imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 50.0;
        imageView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
        imageView.layer.borderWidth = 3.0f;
        imageView.layer.rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
        imageView.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
        imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
UIButton  *mapLaunchButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [mapLaunchButton addTarget:self action:@selector(mapButtonTouch:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
        [mapLaunchButton setTitle:@"ggggggg" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        mapLaunchButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 90);
        mapLaunchButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        [view addSubview:imageView];
        [view addSubview:mapLaunchButton];
        view;
 });
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. Changing UIXXXXX from UILabel to UIView in the following line worked for me:

```
 UIView *sectionHeader = [[UIXXXXX alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectNull];
```

and I didn't use:

```
 self.tableView.tableHeaderView = sectionHeader;
```